# display form results inside different div

Tags: javascript, html

im just wondering how to use javascript (i think it will be javascript but not sure) to have the results of the search action be displayed inside another div, just like sites such as ebay, or even stackoverflow. heres a snippet of my html

```
<div id="searchsign">
   <div style="width: 65%; float:left;height:100%;">
      <form id="searchdivebay" action="searchdivebay.php" method="get">
         <div class="searchbox"><input type="text" name="searchbox" id="searchboxinput"/></div>
         <div class="searchbtn"><input type ="submit" name="searchbutton" value="Search DiveBay"/></div>
      </form>
   </div>
   <div style="width: 35%; float:right;height:100%;">
      <ul class="signreg">
         <li><i>Existing user?</i> <a href="#">SIGN IN</a></li>
         <li><i>or, New user? </i><a href="#">REGISTER</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>   
</div>

<div id="main">
   <div style="height:2px; background-color:blue; top: 0px;"></div>
      <div id="showsearch">

      </div>
```

and yeah, basically i want to have the result of the searchdivebay.php form action be displayed inside the "showsearch" div at the bottom of the code. the script works and i could post the code for that if necessary. but to the point, what is the javascript (if any) to have this functionality?

Comment: the only javascript you would use is if you are reaching this PHP page with AJAX. otherwise, you need to put <?php ?> tags inside the div, check if the form had been submitted, and then render results based on that. since you have a basic form, i'm pretty sure you aren't using AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you will want to use some JQuery like below (which will of course require that you actually include the JQuery library):

```
function fetchData(){
  var url = 'searchdivebay.php';
  // The jQuery way to do an ajax request
  $.ajax({            
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: "", // Your parameters here. looks like you have none
    success: function(html){
      // html contains the literal response from the server
      $("#showsearch").html(html);
    }
  });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use an inline frame and refer to it as target in the from. The inline frame can be wrapped inside a `div` if needed, of course. Example:

```
<form id="searchdivebay" action="searchdivebay.php" method="get"
   target="results">
...
</form>
...
<iframe name="results" width="500" height="200">
</iframe>
```